# SQL query to find rows with similar IDs, which "does not"/"does" have pattern in secondary column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, powerbi

I am trying to write a query for rows that share repeated IDs - related to each other - but holds a specific pattern in secondary columns.

Imagine it's a web shop, who has several stages for each order. Every `orderid` has multiple entries in the table.

I want to exclude some `Orderid` on basis of them having a specific pattern.

Example:

```
Orderid     Stage     OtherInfo
----------------------------------
1           step 1    random info    
1           step 3    random info
1           step 4    random info
3           step 1    random info
3           step 2    random info
5           step 3    random info
4           step 1    random info
4           step 2    random info
4           step 3    random info
```

Now I want to query for the rows, where the corresponding `OrderID` has met the criteria - like for example:

- Has been through "Step 1" & "Step 3" // but not "Step 2"

The expected result being:

```
Orderid      Stage     OtherInfo
-----------------------------------
1            step 1    random info
1            step 3    random info
1            step 4    random info
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the order ids using aggregation and `having`:

```
select orderid
from t
group by orderid
having sum(case when stage = 'step 1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when stage = 'step 3' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when stage = 'step 2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

To get the original rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.orderid in (select orderid
                    from t
                    group by orderid
                    having sum(case when stage = 'step 1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                           sum(case when stage = 'step 3' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
                           sum(case when stage = 'step 2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
                   );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use EXISTS to check the conditions:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename t
WHERE
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.Orderid = t.Orderid AND tablename.stage = 'step 1')
  AND
  EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.Orderid = t.Orderid AND tablename.stage = 'step 3')
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tablename WHERE tablename.Orderid = t.Orderid AND tablename.stage = 'step 2');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
SELECT *
FROM T TT
WHERE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE OrderID = TT.OrderID AND Stage = 'step 1')
           THEN 
      CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE OrderID = TT.OrderID AND Stage = 'step 3')
           THEN 
      CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE OrderID = TT.OrderID AND Stage = 'step 2')
           THEN 1
      END
      END
      END = 1;
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM T TT
WHERE CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE OrderID = TT.OrderID AND Stage = 'step 1')
                AND
                EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE OrderID = TT.OrderID AND Stage = 'step 3')
                AND
                NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM T WHERE OrderID = TT.OrderID AND Stage = 'step 2')
           THEN 1
      END = 1;
```